# Azure Cosmos DB Emulator - Gremlin API, cannot connect through python

Tags: python, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-gremlinapi

I am trying to connect to the emulator through python, I followed the guide on this [page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/local-emulator?tabs=ssl-netstd21#gremlin-api) and was able to connect to the API through the gremlin console. I then tried to connect using python using the following code:

```
from gremlin_python.process.anonymous_traversal import traversal
from gremlin_python.driver.driver_remote_connection import DriverRemoteConnection

conn = DriverRemoteConnection(url='ws://localhost:8901/gremlin',
                              traversal_source='g',
                              username='/dbs/db1/colls/coll1', password='C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==')


g = traversal().withRemote(conn)
g.V().toList()
```

However it fails to connect, `RuntimeError: Connection was closed by server.` I am unsure how to fix this and connect to the Gremlin API through python.

my conf\remote-localcompute.yaml that I use in the gremlin console to connect.

```
  hosts: [localhost]
  port: 8901
  username: /dbs/db1/colls/coll1
  password: C2y6yDjf5/R+ob0N8A7Cgv30VRDJIWEHLM+4QDU5DE2nQ9nDuVTqobD4b8mGGyPMbIZnqyMsEcaGQy67XIw/Jw==
  connectionPool: {
  enableSsl: false}
  serializer: { className: org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.driver.ser.GraphSONMessageSerializerV1d0,
  config: { serializeResultToString: true  }}
```

Comment: I think your URL is missing an "s". Try this, 'wss://<YOUR_ENDPOINT>.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/','g', 
    username="/dbs/<YOUR_DATABASE>/colls/<YOUR_CONTAINER_OR_GRAPH>", 
    password="<YOUR_PASSWORD>"

Comment: The URI portion of the client object should now look similar to this code:  `client = client.Client('wss://<YOUR_ENDPOINT>.gremlin.cosmosdb.azure.com:443/','g', 
    username="/dbs/<YOUR_DATABASE>/colls/<YOUR_CONTAINER_OR_GRAPH>", 
    password="<YOUR_PASSWORD>")`

Comment: Thank you for your help! The issue turned out to be that Cosmos DB Gremlin API does not support the traversal source in python, instead any query has to be submitted directly from a client using submit_async()